# IntelliJ IDEA and Gradle - Cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I have a Gradle file which, whenever I load open it in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5, shows IDE errors for the entire file. Namely all the errors seem to be either:

**java.lang.String errors**

[image: java.lang.String errors]

or

**groovy.lang.Closure errors**

[image: groovy.lang.Closure errors]

I've tried clearing the file's contents and only writing the top line:

```
group 'com.me.blah'
```

but even that results in an error.

For context's sake - this is an individual module in a larger SpringBoot project. This module is a set of simple static files (with Gradle for CSS compilation, static analysis, etc), while the rest are Java modules, and are *not* having Gradle issues.

Can anyone think why IntelliJ would be struggling to understand this Gradle file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone looking for a similar fix, this boiled down to the type of the module. My module was defined in my .iml file as

```
type="WEB_MODULE"
```

I created a new Gradle module and pasted in the same contents, deleted the original, renamed the new module to have the same name as the old one, and everything worked fine. When I diffed the results the only change was that the .iml file now said:

```
type="JAVA_MODULE"
```

So there's the answer, seemingly. Change your module from "web" to "java".

Comment: This did not do the trick for me unfortunately. What did work is "Disable inspection". Not sure if that is the best way to go though.

Comment: I don't have an iml file.

Comment: @Displee it is possibly in your `.idea` directory

Answer (score 61):

I've noticed this often. When creating a new project and using the 'Gradle' template, IntelliJ seems to get it all wrong. So what I've resorted to doing is after creating a new project, delete the .idea and .iml files and re-open the project directly from the Gradle file. IntelliJ seems to better understand what is going on in this case.

Comment: This worked to fix the above error, but it deleted all of my configuration, so the project structure and modules were not stored. Instead, I found that this worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49543980/7267809

Comment: For the sake of clarity, "re-open the project directly from the Gradle file" means: [Open] > Select `build.gradle` > [Open as Project]

Comment: IntelliJ's seemingly poor support for Groovy-style Gradle files made me convert all my Gradle files over to Kotlin by simply adding a `.kt` to the file extension and some relatively minor code changes (see Gradle docs for more info on how to convert to Kotlin in Gradle).

Probably not be the most ideal solution for everyone, but since JetBrains made Kotlin, type-hinting and error support in Gradle files is exponentially better out of the box.

Answer (score 33):

For the first part of the question: `group` is a property, so there must be an assignment, not a function call. The right code is:

```
group = 'com.me.blah'
```

Comment: For those that may ask the question, "then why does `group 'com.me.blah'` work?," take a look at Groovy's [`methodMissing` hook](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_methodmissing). The default Gradle `Project` implementation apparently uses this hook to set the property with the name of the missing method, if it exists.

Comment: This results in `Cannot assign 'String' to 'Object'` for me.

Answer (score 20):

Try File | Invalidate Caches and restart. It worked for me after i mess the syntaxe somewhere else in the file.

Answer (score 19):

I found this suggestion in the IDEA bug tracker([IDEA-142683](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142683)):

> Workaround:
>   One can add a comment such as
>       `//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck`
>   to suppress the warning, but this should not be necessary as these are standard every day Gradle usages.

This issue was recently updated and is marked fixed, ready for release with version 2016.2 release.

Comment: It should be fixed in the next EAP version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142683#comment=27-1448045

Comment: where do I need to add that comment? I am on 15.0.6 and it is annoying

Comment: @stewenson Just put it right above the block of code that is complaining.

Comment: It's happening again to me with version 2019.1.2

Comment: I am on 2020.2 RC version and this is still happening

Answer (score 7):

For me, after trying out all this answers without result, changing the Java SDK of the project did the trick, I was on 1.8 and changed it to the newest one, but still a project level language of 8.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had this issue inside of the buildSrc directory. As I changed language level from 14 down to 8, warning went away. I don't know why java language level is interfering with the Gradle script with Groovy DSL syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Happened to me recently on windows. I tried all of the above but it didn't work.

**What i did:**

1 - I had JAVA_HOME environment variable already set. So IDEA picked that as project SDK and these warnings showed up.

2 - So, i removed the default JAVA_HOME from project SDK and manually added jdk path. Restarted and all warnings were gone.

Maybe it will help someone. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

What I found is that this warning is from Groovy inspection of the Intelliji. So if your project is not pure groovy, you can disable this inspection by going to File -> settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> disable Groovy. Again, just a workaround.

Comment: No need to disable the whole Groovy section but only 'Incompatible type assignments'.
To disable this inspection:
File -> Settings... -> Editor -> Inspections -> Groovy -> Assignment issues -> disable  Incompatible type assignments

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes the issue but updating the JDK corretto-17 to Amazon Corretto-17.0.9 fixed it.