# 'sourceSets' cannot be applied to groovy.lang.Closure<org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet> warning in IntelliJ 2016

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, groovy

`IntelliJ` swears on `sourceSets` entry in `build.gradle`:

[image]

Why and how to fix?

`IntelliJ` is `2016.1`

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905270/intellij-idea-and-gradle-cannot-be-applied-to-groovy-lang-closure) help?

Answer (score 1):

This is false-positive in IJ that I reported already here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141750
For the time being, just ignore it and an update of IJ in the future should make the issue go away.